# How to get time in MM:SS format? (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to write a program that takes a certain time in MM:SS format, but whenever I try this:

```
a = input("Enter time here: ")
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X", line 26, in <module>
    if switch == False and (int(inpt[i])>=0 or int(inpt[i]) <= 9):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ':'
```

Am I supposed to use the `datetime` module to make this work? If so, how?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `minutes, seconds = input("Enter time here: ").split(":")`, assuming you can force your users to always enter their input in `MM:SS` format.

Comment: btw.. you don't get that error from the code you presented, you get it when you try to loop over the user input and encounter the `:` in it. If you insist on doing it your way, check for it as well: `if switch == False and inpt[i] != ":" and (int(inpt[i])>=0 or int(inpt[i]) <= 9):` ...

Comment: Please post more of your code, to establish context. Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output.